# ReactJS error overlay - how do I know if error is actually caught or not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I have some baffling behavior in my development environment for a ReactJS application which makes some API calls with `fetch()` and is bootstrapped with `create-react-app`

When handling the API call, I throw an error which is caught in a middleware elsewhere that wraps around every API call.

I have put `console.log()` in the `catch()` block in this middleware and confirmed it is catching all of these errors. Plus, it displays the error message correctly to the end user, and does not crash the application.

But the weird thing:

- When I'm throwing an error explicitly with `throw`, the ReactJS error overlay pops up and shows it to me.
- When, instead, the same code throws an error on the `json()` call (that is, the API call didn't return valid JSON), this is again caught by the same middleware and the error message is displayed the same way in the UI, but the ReactJS error overlay does NOT show up.

I even tried throwing `SyntaxError` explicitly to see what would happen, but in that case the error overlay does show up.

My question is, basically: is this anything to worry about? The error overlay is only functional on the development environment after all, and I'm not sure if it actually indicates that these errors will cause crashes/problems in production. I am not sure what the rules are for when it shows up or not. Is it expected that the overlay won't show up for an uncaught `Json.parse()` error, but will show up for everything else? When the error overlay shows up, is it anything to worry about if I can just close it and the app itself is still working correctly?

Comment: The `.json()` happens in an async function and that is the reason it is not caught by your middleware. It happens outside the render and commit phases of React. Read https://medium.com/trabe/catching-asynchronous-errors-in-react-using-error-boundaries-5e8a5fd7b971

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Thanks. ...However it seems to be caught by the middleware... I see the JSON syntax error if I `console.log` the caught error from `catch()` block of the middleware. This is `catch()` from Fetch API btw. Do you mean that is why it's not caught by react error overlay?

Answer (score 1):

Errors in React are caught by [Error Boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html).

According to docs they can't catch errors in:

- Event handlers
- Asynchronous code (e.g. setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame callbacks)
- Server side rendering
- Errors thrown in the error boundary itself (rather than its children)

`fetch()` is an asynchronous code and React can't catch those errors. You should have `try/catch` block for `async` code or `.catch()` handler for promises to handle errors yourself (for example update React state to indicate that an error has happened and show the error message).